# After fresh instal of Ubuntu 18.04 on Yoga 3 pro bluetooth didn't work

Tags: bluetooth, lenovo, broadcom, 18.04

After fresh instal of Ubuntu 18.04 on Yoga 3 pro Bluetooth didn't work

`dmesg`

output had a line as the following:

`hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702A1-0489-e07a.hcd not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded 'BCM20702A1-0489-e07a.hcd' from https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/tree/master/brcm and copied it to /lib/firmware/brcm/

maybe the easiest way to put it in the console:

`cd /lib/firmware/brcm/`

`sudo wget https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/tree/master/brcm/BCM20702A1-0489-e07a.hcd`

After restart the Bluetooth worked again...

Cheers :)

Comment: Thank you! This sorted my Yoga3.